# Different method to get the sites list programmatically

Tags: c#, sharepoint, office365

I am using office 365. I have created number of sites on Sharepoint. I want to get the list of all sites and site Id's programmatically(using c#).

I have used GraphServiceClient "await m_GraphClient.Groups.Request().GetAsync()".

But i want to know more ways to get the list of sites.

Comment: I am using office 365. I have created number of sites on Sharepoint. I want to get the list of all sites and site Id's programatically(using c#).
I have used GraphServiceClient "await 
m_GraphClient.Groups.Request().GetAsync()".

But i want to know more ways to get the list of sites.
Also i want o find particular site.
If i have two site with same name then how do i find the particular site
For e.g.
site 1 -: Display name = ABC
 URL = https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/ABC
site 2:- Display name = ABC
URL = https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/ABCD
Then how to find particular site

Answer (score 2):

You could try search.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites?search=*
```

Sample in SPFx

```
this.props.context.msGraphClientFactory
      .getClient()
      .then((client: MSGraphClient): void => {       
        client          
          .api("sites?search=*")
          .version("v1.0")
          .get((error, response: any, rawResponse?: any) => {
            console.log(response);            
          });
      })
```

Comment: If i have two site with same name then how do i implement search query

For e.g.
site 1 -: Display name = ABC
             URL = https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/ABC
site 2:- Display name = ABC
          URL = https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/ABCD

Then how to find particular site